# Tab Bar not showing when push notifications clicked and goes to a Specific ViewController in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3, apple-push-notifications

I am receiving `Push Notifications` when i click on Notification i want to go to a particular `ViewController` opens when click i click on SlideMenu didSelectRow. I tried many SO links but below code i am able to go to a particular `ViewController` but problem is tabBar it not showing.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let ringingVC = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RaffleResultViewController") as? RaffleResultViewController

    window?.rootViewController = ringingVC
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding  RaffleResultViewController on Window, instead, Navigate to RaffleResultViewController using Navigation Controller?

Comment: @h.kishan could u tell me how

Comment: @h.kishan RaffleResultViewController is the view controller which i want to navigate when i click on push notifications and tabor also appears

Answer (score 0):

```
let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let ringingVC = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RaffleResultViewController") as? RaffleResultViewController

let selectedVC = window.rootViewController

if let nav = selectedVC as? UINavigationController{
    nav.pushViewController(ringingVC, animated: true)
}else{
    selectedVC.present(ringingVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

// USE this

Comment: checking ur answer

Comment: it is not opening that specific view controller it remains on the page which opens after autologin with tab bar @h.kishan